# How to send message to GCM for Push notification using Web API C#

Tags: cordova, push-notification, send

I am currently working on push notification using Push Plugin for PhoneGAP android.
Need to send a message through WEB API on GCM server.

I Had know clue regarding this.

Kindly help me out